# performance issue of watir table object processing. How to make Nokogiri html table into array?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, watir, watir-webdriver

The following works but is always very slow, seemingly halting my scraping program and its Firefox or Chrome browser for even whole minutes *per page*:

```
pp recArray = $browser.table(:id,"recordTable").to_a
```

Getting the HTML table's text or html source is fast though:

```
htmlcode = $browser.table(:id,"recordTable").html  # .text shows only plaintext portion like lynx
```

How might I be able to create the same **recArray** (each element from a `<TR>`) using for example a Nokogiri object holding only that table's html?

`recArray =  Nokogiri::HTML(htmlcode).` **??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want each tr in the table?

```
Nokogiri::HTML($browser.html).css('table[@id="recordTable"] > tr')
```

This gives a NodeSet which can be more useful than Array. Of course there's still to_a

Comment: That might do it, thanks! I will test things out since I am hoping to replace my already extensive usage of `$browser.table(:id,"recordTable").to_a`, where in all cases I further process/parse the array's rows and cells differently, eg. sometimes into CSV, so I have to take care to try and keep it transparent and not to break things.

Comment: I don't know what the `>` was for but my array came alive after I junked it:  `doc = Nokogiri::HTML(File.new("savedcopy.html"));  puts doc.css('table[@class="detail-table w-Positions"] tr').to_a`

Comment: After I had extracted that array, I had further needed to strip the resulting rows and cells from any Nokogiri type objects back down to Ruby primary types: `recArray.map {|row| row.css("td").map {|c| c.text}.to_a }` to maintain transparency, else my program was crashing.  This 2D Array now holds Strings free of html tags, good.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a blog post about that a few days ago: http://zeljkofilipin.com/watir-nokogiri/

If you have further questions, ask.

Comment: Great blog, thank you. I was just extrapolating from it to post back a code answer here, something like, `recArray = Nokogiri::HTML(tablehtml).css("tr")` but another answer beat me to it.   I am looking to do a global drop-in replacement in all my code where I need to extract rows as array records; the cumulative delay is that bad.

Answer (score 1):

Thought it would be useful to sum up all the steps here and there:

The question was how to produce the same array object filled with strings from the page's text content that a **Watir::Webdriver Table #to_a** might produce, but much faster:

```
 recArray = Nokogiri::HTML(htmlcode). **??**
```

So instead of this as I was doing before:

```
  recArray=$browser.table(:class, 'detail-table w-Positions').to_a
```

I send the whole page's html as a string to Nokogiri to let it do the parsing:

```
  recArray=Nokogiri::HTML($browser.html).css('table[@class="detail-table w-Positions"] tr').to_a
```

Which found me the rows of the table I want and put them into an array.

Not done yet since the elements of that array are still Nokogiri (Table Row?) types, which barfed when I attempted things like `.join(",")` (useful for writing into a .CSV file or database for instance)

So the following iterates through each row element, turning each into an array of pure Ruby String types, containing only the text content of each table cell stripped of html tags:

```
 recArray= recArray.map {|row| row.css("td").map {|c| c.text}.to_a }  # Could of course be merged with above to even longer, nastier one-liner
```

Each cell had previously also been a Nokogiri Element type, done away with the `.text` mapping.

Significant speedup achieved.

Next I wonder what it would take to simply override the `#to_a` method of every **Watir::Webdriver Table** object globally in my Ruby code files....

(I realize that may not be 100% compatible but it would spare me so much code rewriting. Am willing to try in my *personal.lib.rb* include file.)